# PHP replace string for other string

Tags: php, string, replace

I have a doubt, it may be something simple but I have no knowledge to solve it.

I get a string in php

```
$ string = "[link = someUrl] Text [link]"
```

And I would like to turn this string into:

```
"<a href='someUrl'> Text <a/>"
```

How do I change the URL? and How Can I do the opposite?

Remember that the string belongs to a text with more strings of these gifts.

Comment: can you please clarify what you mean by the last line?

Comment: There are several occurrences like this in the whole text.

Answer (score 1):

Short **`preg_replace`** solution:

```
$s = "[link=someUrl] Text [/link]";
$result = preg_replace('#\[[^=]+=([^]]+)\]([^[]+).*#', '<a href=\'$1\'>$2</a>', $s);

print_r($result);
```

The output (as web page source code):

```
<a href='someUrl'> Text </a>
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you! and how would it be to do the opposite?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code

```
function transformText($string) {
    preg_match("/\[link\=([^\]]*)\](.*?)\[\/link]/", $string, $matches);
    $someUrl = $matches[1];
    $text = $matches[2];
    $newString = "<a href='$someUrl'>$text</a>";
    return $newString;
}

$string = "[link=someUrl] Text [/link]"; // Test string
echo (transformText($string));
```

Live demo for the regex used : https://regex101.com/r/tzVfmH/4

**Note** : The above code works only if there's a single `[link]`, `[/link]` pair.
If multiple occurrences are to be handled then its better to use regex search and replace, using php's [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) as suggested in [RomanPerekhrest's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46623880/3293087).

Comment: I change a little thing, look my string now:

"[link=someUrl] Text [/link]"

What I need to change in your code?

Comment: @DaniloRibeiro sure. I've changed the regex to match the question

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work :(, I copy your code and use and nothing happened

Comment: @DaniloRibeiro I think that the string must be set. I have updated the code. Can you try and run it ?

Comment: yeah, I copy your code and paste , my php version is 5.4.43.

Comment: @DaniloRibeiro did it work? Did you get any error? If yes, can you please post it here.. maybe I can help :)

Comment: No erros, just out put is <a href='' ></a>, don´t get the maches, i don´t now why, i solved using this  preg_replace('#\[[^=]+=([^]]+)\]([^[]+).*#', '<a href=\'$1\'>$2</a>', $s); from RomanPerekhrest answer, thank you very much